# How can I add an extra key and value to my FormControl data that isn't native to the data model being injected?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I stumbled into yet another conundrum with Angular 2.  To begin adding functionality to my form where I can tell Angular to do something based on what answer is selected, I was pointed towards learning how to generate reactive forms.  Now that I've actually got it working and moved on to the next part of making use of it's reactive nature I see that the way I have things set up for the `name` value of the radio buttons doesn't work with `formControlName` because instead of putting the same `name="nameOfThing"` for each option I want to show up with the radio button, I just called it in the parent and binded the `name` value directly to it.  Here's the code so you know what I'm talking about.

Data

```
{
question: 'How do you feel about your current image?',
id      : 'img-q1',
name    : 'img-ques1', //I define the name here
answers : [
    {
        id      : 'exp0101q',
        answer  : 'Its fine as is.'
        name    : 'theName' //rather than here for each answer.
    },
    {
        id      : 'exp0102q',
        answer  : 'I want to make minor adjustments.'
    },
    {
        id      : 'exp0103q',
        answer  : 'I want to change my image.'
    },
    {
        id      : 'exp0104q',
        answer  : 'Ive never wanted to use a particular image until now.'
    }
    ]
}
```

Seeing that the name needs to be the same for each radio button in order for them to work properly I felt the database would start to become bigger than it needs to be over time with so many different answers to more questions.  This is a local `const` I defined for the sake of following along with the tutorial but is otherwise the same as what I have in my FireBase database.

The way I called it in my `*ngFor` was like this

```
<input type="radio" name="question.name" <!-- remember it's not in "answers" -->
                    [attr.id]   = "answer.id"
                    [value]= "answer.answer"
/>
```

and everything rendered perfectly.

Now that I've converted it into a reactive form I have this in the template.

```
<div formGroupName="answers"><!-- doesn't have a "name" property -->
    <div *ngFor="let ans of quesForm.value.answers">
        <input type="radio" formControlName="quesForm.value.name"
        <!-- trying same philosophy of going up a tier doesn't work --> 
            [attr.id]="ans.id"
            [attr.value]="ans.answer"
            />
        <label>{{ans.answer}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

So of course I'm getting errors telling me it can't find the control with that name because `name:` doesn't exist in `answers`.  If I swap out `formControlName="..."` for regular ol `name="..."` it works, but that defeats the purpose of why I even went through everything I went through to use it as a reactive form.

The overall logic I'm currently thinking around to make use of the ""reactiveness"" is

- Use `name` attribute to select all the radio buttons.
- Use `id` to identify which is selected in whatever script I have to come up with to detect it.
- Use `id` again in the parent component through `if` statements to trigger different `*ngIf` components based on what the user selects.

I'll be using it elsewhere in the site, some instances the "answers" will be saved, other instances, such as this one, they're more or less for functionality on the user's end to get them in front of the right info and examples.  So I want to be able to use unique names for each question to avoid instances of having 3 of them rendering on the same page and somehow something gets confused.

So far my component's class looks like this.

```
export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {

    question: QuestionModel;
    quesForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private qservice : QuestionService, private fbuild : FormBuilder) {}



    ngOnInit(){
        this.qservice.getQuestions().subscribe(Question => {
            this.question = Question;
            this.createForm();
        });

        //console.log(this.question);
        console.log(this.quesForm);
    }

    createForm() {
        this.quesForm = this.fbuild.group({
            question: this.question.question,
            id      : this.question.id,
            name    : this.question.name,
            answers : this.fbuild.array([])
        });
        this.setAnswers(this.question.answers);
    }

    get answers(): FormArray {
        return this.quesForm.get('answers') as FormArray;
    };

    setAnswers(answers : Answers[]){
        const answersFGs = answers.map(answers => this.fbuild.group(answers));
        const answersFormArray= this.fbuild.array(answersFGs);
        this.quesForm.setControl('answers', answersFormArray)
    }


}
```

The only thing I can rationalize is maybe I'd have to come up with something inside the `setAnswers()` function somewhere. Maybe something like

```
const name = this.quesform.name;
```

and inject `name` into the `.map()` somehow?  Or should it be done some other way?

Comment: I am not sure I see what the issue is, it should all work from what I can see, [here's a Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1DsOU7TJIP4HhqaVmqte?p=preview), it shows a working version of this excluding `FormGroupName` implementation- Is this where you issue lies?

Comment: yes it does work without the `FormGroupName`, but that's the thing, I need to use that in order to make functional use of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
const answersFGs = answers.map(
    answers => this.fbuild.group(
         Object.assign( {name: this.quesform.name }, answers)));
```

Comment: that's giving me an error telling me `name:` isn't a property of `FormGroup` so I think this is more or less trying to manually fill in the `name` field assuming it's already there, rather than creating and defining it.